# SQLAlchemy ORM: "AttributeError: Could not locate column in row"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, mariadb, pymysql

I'm learning SQLAlchemy right now, but I've encountered an error that puzzles me. Yes, there are similar questions here on SO already, but none of them seem to be solved.

My goal is to use the ORM mode to query the database. So I create a model:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, registry
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

database_url = "mysql+pymysql://..."

mapper_registry = registry()
Base = mapper_registry.generate_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32))


engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=True)
mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

New I want to load the whole row for all entries in the table:

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    for row in session.execute(select(User)):
        print(row.name)

#- Error: #

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    print(row.name)
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'name'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't I be able to access the fields of the ORM model? Or am I misunderstanding the idea of ORM?

I'm using Python 3.8 with PyMySQL 1.0.2 and SQLAlchemy 1.4.15 and the server runs MariaDB.

This is example is as minimal as I could make it, I hope anyone can point me in the right direction. Interestingly, inserting new rows works like a charm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`session.execute(select(User))` will return a list of `Row` instances (tuples), which you need to unpack:

```
for row in session.execute(select(Object)):
    # print(row[0].name)  # or 
    print(row["Object"].name)
```

But I would use the `.query` which returns instances of `Object` directly:

```
for row in session.query(Object):
    print(row.name)
```

Comment: The `.query` method was exactly what I was looking for! Cannot believe that I didn't find it after reading the documentation for several hours.

Comment: yeh, I would note that query is deprecated in the v2 API

Comment: @ChrisSewell: Is there a function that would produce the same result, for those of us who don't like unpacking tuples unnecessarily?

Comment: Found a fix for now: for row, in session.execute(select(Object)):

Comment: @MontanaBurr `session.execute(select(Object)).all()`. The `scalars()` method unpacks the tuples. You can omit it to get the tuples as is.

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to add some to what above @Van said.

You can get object instances using `session.execute()` as well.

```py
for row in session.execute(select(User)).scalars().all():
    print(row.name)
```

Which is mentioned in [migrating to 2.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html).

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error today when executing queries that join two or more tables.

It turned out that after updating `psycopg2` (2.8.6 -> 2.9.3), `SQLAlchemy` (1.3.23 -> 1.4.39), and `flask-sqlalchemy` (2.4.4 -> 2.5.1) the `Query.all()` method return type is a list of  `sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row`s and before it was a list of `tuple`s. For instance:

```
query = database.session.query(model)
query = query.outerjoin(another_model, some_field == another_field)
results = query.all()
# type(results[0]) -> sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row
if isinstance(results[0], (list, tuple)):
     # Serialize as a list of rows
else:
     # Serialize as a single row
```