# AttributeError("can't set attribute") error when trying to update a table using Flask-SqlAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When trying to update a row value in a table using Flask-SQLAlchemy, I get the following error:

```
>>> row.meta_value = "new value"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/work/breakfast4you/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/row.py", line 219, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I'm testing the code before implementing into the actual file, so I'm running it through `flask shell`. I've ran other queries through `flask shell` so I know it's not a problem with it.

The table belongs to a MySQL database connected through a MariaDB engine. This is its table model:

```py
t_aus_postmeta = db.Table(
    'aus_postmeta',
    db.Column('post_id', db.BigInteger, nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue()),
    db.Column('meta_key', db.String(255, 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')),
    db.Column('meta_value', db.String(collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'))
)
```

And this is the query I'm running to retrieve the row.

```py
>>> row = db.session.query(t_aus_postmeta).\
            filter(t_aus_postmeta.c.post_id == 740).\
                filter(t_aus_postmeta.c.meta_key == "_billing_shipment").\
                    first()
```

I was able to run the same query using plain SQL through DBeaver:

```
UPDATE aus_postmeta 
SET meta_value = "Cumpleaños"
WHERE post_id = 740
AND meta_key = "_billing_shipment";
```

Taking into account [the accepted answer to this almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397734/14311397), I tried:

- Querying only one row, to avoid a `tuple` object.
- Avoid a `.filter` like `filter(meta.c.meta_key.in_([<array of meta_keys>]))` (which was my first intention, since I need to edit several rows).

Following the advise on that same question, I also ran the following test to see if the object was of type `tuple` . I doubted it, (since it's only one row), but still:

```py
>>> row
(740, '_billing_shipment', 'Cumpleaños')
>>> type(row)
<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>
>>> issubclass(type(row), tuple)
False
```

**EDIT:**
Looking further into my package versions,

```
SQLAlchemy == 1.4.31
Flask-SQLAlchemy == 2.5.1
```

[This GitHub comment suggests that it was fixed on Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/910#issuecomment-802098285) and subsequently, [this answer states that it's no longer necessary to downgrade SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66652728/14311397), so my package versions should have this issue fixed.

What else could be causing this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since I had the exacte same Location where the Error is raised (... engine/row.py", line 219,), maybe this helps you as much as it helped me:

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67631022/12584555) explains the difference between `session.execute(select(Object))` and `session.query(Object)` and if you use have a `Row` object you need to unpack it.

Use:

```
row["Object"].meta_value = "new value"
```

Instead of:

```
row.meta_value = "new value"
```

Comment: Hey, using this I got the following error: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: Could not locate column in row for column 'Object'