# sqlalchemy can't access model's column value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

when i access the name column it give me error
`AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'name'`
however when i print category it is printed, because it exists in db but can't get column attribute.

```py
parent_id = 29
with Session(e) as session:
    category = session.execute(select(Category).where(Category.wp_id == parent_id)).first()
    print(category[0].name)
    cat[0].child_categories.append(keyword)
    session.add(cat)
    session.commit()
```

model:

```py
class Category(Base):

    __tablename__ = "category"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    wp_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = Column(String)

    child_categories = relationship("Keyword", back_populates="parent_category", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

**note**: this is pure sqlalchemy

**edit**

```
>>> from db.operations import add_keyword_to_db
>>> add_keyword_to_db(29, 'dota 2', 30)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Projects\ongoing_projects\wp_auto\db\operations.py", line 62, in add_keyword_to_db
    print(cat.name)
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'name`
```

this is the function that prints the name,

```
def add_keyword_to_db(parent_id: int, keyword_name: str, keyword_wp_id) -> None:
    global engine
    with Session(engine) as session:
        cat = session.execute(select(Category).where(Category.wp_id == parent_id)).first()
        print(cat.name)
        # keyword = Keyword(name=keyword_name, wp_id=keyword_wp_id)
        # cat.child_categories.append(keyword)
        # session.add(cat)
        # session.commit()
```

and as you can see here in database its clearly there
[image: database]

Comment: You're printing `cat.name` whereas the variable you've assigned from your query is `category`. `cat` must be a variable elsewhere which is being accessed which doesn't have a `name` attribute

Comment: no no sorry thats my mistake i forgot to edit it.

Comment: it is category, and the issue is still there

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67631022/5901382

Comment: see the edited part of my addkeyword function, it gives me `errorsqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row' is not mapped`

Comment: its resolved it forgot to add newly created keyword to session